Zebra EPL Print Command - Windows/Delphi/batch
I'm trying to send a print command to Zebra using EPL:
For Windows I use the following command:
Type test.txt > "\\desktop-AB123\ZDesigner ZD230-203dpi ZPL"

test.txt
N
R30,10
D10
A210,0,0,1,1,1,N,"MATHEUS"
B285,65,0,1,2,1,70,N,"s"
A210,20,0,1,1,1,N,"210"
A210,35,0,1,1,1,N,"12000"
A330,35,0,1,1,1,N,"12"
A210,50,0,1,1,1,N,"V"
A430,50,0,1,1,1,N,"DN"
A195,220,3,1,1,1,R,"   TEST"
A210,143,0,1,1,1,N,"TEST"
A210,158,0,1,1,1,N,"TEST"
A210,173,0,1,1,1,N,"TEST"
A450,173,0,1,1,1,N,"TEST"
A210,188,0,1,1,1,N,"H"
A210,206,0,1,1,1,N,""
P1

N

It works perfectly using the same text file in the Zebra Utilities sendFile or in Windows printers.
I tried to do it the following way in Delphi 7:
procedure PrintFileWithCommand(const FileName, PrinterName: string);
var
  Command: string;
begin
  Command := 'cmd /C type "' + FileName + '" > "' + PrinterName + '"';
  WinExec(PChar(Command), SW_HIDE);
end;

procedure SendRawDataToPrinter(const PrinterName: string; const RawData: string);
var
hPrinter: THandle;
DocInfo: TDocInfo1;
BytesWritten: DWORD;
PData: PAnsiChar;
begin
if not OpenPrinter(PChar(PrinterName), hPrinter, nil) then
raise Exception.Create('Error opening printer: ' + PrinterName);
try
FillChar(DocInfo, SizeOf(DocInfo), 0);
DocInfo.pDocName := 'EPL Command';
DocInfo.pOutputFile := nil;
DocInfo.pDatatype := 'RAW';
if StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, @DocInfo) = 0 then
raise Exception.Create('Error starting document on printer.');
if not StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) then
raise Exception.Create('Error starting page on printer.');

PData := PAnsiChar(RawData);
if not WritePrinter(hPrinter, PData, Length(RawData), BytesWritten) then
raise Exception.Create('Error sending data to printer.');

EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
finally
ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
end;
end;

procedure PrintFile(const FileName: string; PrinterIndex: Integer);
var
  F: TextFile;
  EPLContent: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if not FileExists(FileName) then
  begin
    MessageBox(Application.Handle, 'Not found !', PChar('AT!'), MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING);
    Exit;
  end;

  EPLContent := TStringList.Create;
  try 
  
    EPLContent.LoadFromFile(FileName);
 
    Printer.PrinterIndex := PrinterIndex; 
    
    AssignPrn(F);
    ReWrite(F);
    try
      for I := 0 to EPLContent.Count - 1 do
        WriteLn(F, EPLContent[I]);
    finally
      CloseFile(F);
    end;

 
    MessageBox(Application.Handle, 'Sucess !', PChar('AT!'), MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage('error: ' + E.Message);
  end;
  FreeAndNil(EPLContent);
end;

I tried using a .prn:
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('cmd.exe'), PChar('/c type ' + file+ ' > ' + imp), nil, SW_HIDE);

But without success either.
Some commands are sent to the printer spool but it does not print. But if I send the same text via sendFile (Zebra Utilities or SendFile printer properties), it works normally.
Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Have you tried copy or copy /b instead of type? Does your .txt have the correct format (ASCII or ANSI, not UTF)?

Yes, it operates normally in manual sending as informed.
Copy, Print and type didn't work

Do you have to use EPL or can you use ZPL, too? I wrote a ZPL parser with preview capabilities

only epl, but the problem itself is just sending to printer and printing being done. Manual sending with the same epl in a .txt operates normally and prints
